# Can i test a website is responsive design

Tags: node.js, response

As the title says: is there a method to test a website is `responsive` use `node` or other script on background.

there is many web sites provide screenshot, but i want to use script to check it.

now i want to use `WebView` to show website on phone so i want to know if the website is responsive, if it is `responsive`, i will show it, or not

there is method to save all website's host name, and when there is another request, i will check data table

Comment: @EvilBeer check if the website has `media query` css, but this is Inefficient

Answer (score 1):

The term responsive generally just indicates that the website uses CSS media selectors in order to modify its layout based upon device attributes. You could probably download any linked CSS and check for the use of media selectors but this is unlikely to be a bullet-proof way of detecting for a responsive site.

Additionally, there's no way you can detect what scripting language is used on the backend of a website. You could guess based upon headers and other information coming back in a response but, again, it's not a bullet-proof way of determining whether the page is dynamically generated or not.

What exactly do you need to do this for?

Comment: Thanks you quickly reply, i have same thought with you.  i want to        show it on phone, so i check responsive first, and let the UI perfect